# SQL selecting random records to fulfill category

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this table `QUESTIONS` that has 500 records
with the following columns:

```
Q_ID
Q_difficulty('easy','medium','hard')
Q_subject('MATH','SCIENCE','LANGUAGE','HISTORY')
Question(the actual question)
```

I need to get 100 random records consisting of 20 easy, 60 medium and 20 hard but I have to consider about getting 25% of each subject.

I know how to get easy, medium and hard by doing:

```
go
select top 20 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='easy' order by NEWID()
go
select top 60 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='medium' order by NEWID()
go
select top 20 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='hard' order by NEWID()
```

My problem is how to make the query have 25% of each subject.
Im using SQL server by the way :(

Comment: Do you need the subjects evenly split between easy, medium, and hard questions?

Comment: @ErikE No he want in the ratio of **`easy:medium:hard = 1:3:1`** and **`Math:Sceience:Language:History = 1:1:1:1`**

Comment: Nope. Its not really needed, I just have to make sure I have 25% of each subject and the 20:60:20 ratio of the difficulty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   X.*
FROM
   (VALUES
      ('easy', 5), ('medium', 15), ('hard', 5)
   ) D (Difficulty, Qty)
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES
      ('MATH'), ('SCIENCE'), ('LANGUAGE'), ('HISTORY')
   ) S (Subject)
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP (D.Qty)
         Q.*
      FROM
         dbo.Questions Q
      WHERE
         D.Difficulty = Q.Difficulty
         AND D.Subject = Q.Subject
      ORDER BY
         NewID()
   ) X
```

Comment: What does X stand for? And also what is Cross Join and Cross Apply?

Comment: `X` is a table alias assigned to the derived table in parentheses immediately before it. `CROSS JOIN` means a join with no correlating condition, resulting in a Cartesian product, also sometimes call a cross product. In this case I joined together three derived tables (none of them refer directly to a real table, but have a query inside parentheses). `CROSS APPLY` introduces a table or subquery that is not explicity joined with an `ON` clause (similar to `CROSS JOIN`) but is allowed to have outer references (where for example in table `X` it can refer to columns from table D.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to break it down to the individual percentages:

```
select top 5 * INTO #tmp from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='easy' AND Q_subject='MATH' order by NEWID();
INSERT INTO #tmp
select top 5 * from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='easy' AND Q_subject='SCIENCE' order by NEWID();
INSERT INTO #tmp
select top 5 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='easy' AND Q_subject='LANGUAGE' order by NEWID();
INSERT INTO #tmp
select top 5 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='easy' AND Q_subject='HISTORY' order by NEWID();
INSERT INTO #tmp
select top 15 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='medium' AND Q_subject='MATH' order by NEWID();
INSERT INTO #tmp
select top 15 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='medium' AND Q_subject='SCIENCE' order by NEWID();
INSERT INTO #tmp
select top 15 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='medium' AND Q_subject='LANGUAGE' order by NEWID();
INSERT INTO #tmp
select top 15 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='medium' AND Q_subject='HISTORY' order by NEWID();
INSERT INTO #tmp
select top 5 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='hard' AND Q_subject='MATH' order by NEWID();
INSERT INTO #tmp
select top 5 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='hard' AND Q_subject='SCIENCE' order by NEWID();
INSERT INTO #tmp
select top 5 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='hard' AND Q_subject='LANGUAGE' order by NEWID();
INSERT INTO #tmp
select top 5 from QUESTIONS where Q_difficulty='hard' AND Q_subject='HISTORY' order by NEWID();
SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

Comment: "Have to" is so... inflexible.  :)

Comment: Well, just learnt something new again. Thanks for introducing us to some features of MSSQL 2008: VALUES - nice one, and of course CROSS APPLY of MSSQL 2005. ;-)

Comment: @cars10 Be sure to tag people when there are more than 2 people in the conversation (including yourself) and the person is not the OP or question/answer writer!